# How to get the sum of a column between a specific date range in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder

I'm trying to find a way to get the sum of a column between a specific date range.
I have a data set that contains data from 2016-2019 and would like to use one table to hold all four years to allow for interactive sorting later on. I have create parameters with set values for the 1/1/201x and 12/31/201x.

This is what I'm currently trying, but receiving an error.

```
=IIF(Fields!TxnDate.Value >= Parameters!start2016.Value AND Fields!TxnDate.Value <= Parameters!end2016.Value, sum(Fields!Amount.Value),0)
```

Error

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for the text box ‘Total2016’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
```

What do I need to do to get the expression to sum the total amount in the column in the date range?

Note: the total amount will be setup as a currency.

Comment: As Hannover pointed out, the IIF/SUM expression is incorrect, but the error you are getting is a scope error. Where are you putting this expression? Is it in a table/matrix or just in a textbox? If it is just in a textbox you will need to add a scope depending on what you want to evaluate, if you want to do the sum/iff on the entire dataset then use the dataset name in quotes as the scope something `=SUM(IIF(Fields!X.Value > Parameters!myParameterName.Value, Fields!myValue.Value, 0), "myDataSetName")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to move your SUM to outside the IIF.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!TxnDate.Value >= Parameters!start2016.Value AND Fields!TxnDate.Value <= Parameters!end2016.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, 0))
```

If your amount isn't an integer, you'll need to convert the `0` to decimal with `CDEC(0)` otherwise you'd get a Can't Aggregate Different Types error.

Is your date a text string? Your evaluation may not work correctly if it's text in a mm/dd/yyyy format. You may need to convert to date to compare with `CDATE`.